# cant close html popup even though xpaths and querySelector should work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

If i open a incognito chrome browser and go to this URL:

After a couple seconds a popup appears, I am trying to close this popup in javascript:
[image]

So I'm trying to get an element I can click to close the popup, the xpath `(//div[@class='frame-container']//div[@class='layer-wiziwig']//div)[1]` finds one element, but then if i try to get that element and then click it in the console, it doesnt find anything:

```
document.evaluate(`(//div[@class='frame-container']//div[@class='layer-wiziwig']//div)[1]`, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue
```

So I tried a different method by getting the element using: `document.querySelectorAll('div .layer-wiziwig')[0]` which should also work but just returns null.

How can i close this popup using javascript??

Comment: you could try `document.querySelectorAll('[class="design-layer vcenter"] [style^="opacity:0;"]')[0].click()`

Comment: returns 'undefined' as well, it seems like occasionally on this webpage the popup becomes impossible to query or select with javascript

Comment: By finding an element to click on, you're telling the page that you're closing the popup. A different way to go about it is to select the element of interest and then call it's `.remove()` method. That just removes it from the DOM. `document.getElementById(xxx).remove()` called for the following values of xxx seems to do it: 'ju_store', 'juStore', 'ju_overlay' and finally, 'justuno_form'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is inside an iframe you need to access the iframe document with contentWindow.document
e.g

```
document.querySelector('.ju_iframe').contentWindow.document.querySelector('.layer-wiziwig')
```